# Count the same list's occur frequency in a multi-dimensional list?

Tags: python, list

I have a multi-dimensional list as like below

```
multilist = [[1,2],[3,4,5],[3,4,5],[5,6],[5,6],[5,6]]
```

How can I get below results fast:

```
[1,2]: count 1 times
[3,4,5]: count 2 times
[5,6]: count 3 times
```

and also get the unique multi-dimensional list (remove duplicates) :

```
multi_list = [[1,2],[3,4,5],[5,6]]
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just curious, have you tried anything? Done any research?

Comment: Have you tried something or you're asking us to do your homework ?

Comment: `map(list, set(map(tuple, multilist)))` ?

Comment: @thebjorn Please no.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen just trying to be "helpful" :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tuples which are hashable and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> multilist = [[1,2],[3,4,5],[3,4,5],[5,6],[5,6],[5,6]]
>>> multituples = [tuple(l) for l in multilist]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> tc = Counter(multituples)
>>> tc
Counter({(5, 6): 3, (3, 4, 5): 2, (1, 2): 1})
```

To get the set of elements you just need the keys:

```
>>> tc.keys()
dict_keys([(1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (5, 6)])
```

Comment: This does the set part as well... (by getting the keys)

Comment: I'm guessing the order of your final result isn't guaranteed to be the same as the original order?

Comment: Nope, dictionaries are not ordered. Sets are (usually) not ordered as well.

Comment: This is really what I have been looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Try and read the docs - they're usually helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to guarantee that the order of the unique items is the same as in the original list, you could do something like:

```
>>> class Seen(set):
...     def __contains__(self, item):
...         res = super(Seen, self).__contains__(item)
...         self.add(item)
...         return res
...
>>> seen = Seen()
>>> [item for item in multilist if tuple(item) not in seen]
[[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [5, 6]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

---

You can try like this,

```
>>> multilist = [[1,2],[3,4,5],[3,4,5],[5,6],[5,6],[5,6]]
>>> c = [multilist.count(l) for l in multilist]
>>> for ind, l in enumerate(multilist):
...   print( "%s: count %d times" % (str(l), c[ind]))
... 
[1, 2]: count 1 times
[3, 4, 5]: count 2 times
[3, 4, 5]: count 2 times
[5, 6]: count 3 times
[5, 6]: count 3 times
[5, 6]: count 3 times

>>> {str(item): multilist.count(item) for item in multilist }
{'[1, 2]': 1, '[3, 4, 5]': 2, '[5, 6]': 3}
```

Comment: That is only (kind of) half of the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, like you answer, but it is not enough... Can it report the as like the dict:{'[1,2]': 1, '[3,4,5]': 2, '[5,6]': 3}

Answer (score 0):

As @ReutSharabani suggested, you can use tuples as dictionary keys, and then convert back to lists for display purposes.  The code below doesn't reply on `collections` (not that there's anything wrong with that).

```
multilist = [[1,2],[3,4,5],[3,4,5],[5,6],[5,6],[5,6]]
histogram = {}
for x in multilist:
    xt = tuple(x)
    if xt not in histogram:
        histogram[xt] = 1
    else:
        histogram[xt] += 1
for k,c in histogram.items():
    print "%r: count %d times" % (list(k),c)
print [list(x) for x in histogram.keys()]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using repr( alist) to convert it to its text string representation?

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)
for e in multilist: d[ repr(e)] += 1

for k,v in d.items(): print "{0}: count {1} times".format( k,v)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a dictionary for this

```
count_data = {}

for my_list in multilist:
    count_data.setdefault(tuple(my_list), 0)
    count_data[tuple(my_list)] += 1
```

Comment: This doesn't address the whole of the question.  Also, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.